# Adding more than one line per case in a switch-case statement (python)

Tags: python, switch-statement, syntax-error

I'm new to programming and trying to understand how to use a switch-case statement in python. My problem is a syntax error that occurs when I try to use a statement that has more than one line per case. Is this possible? What am I missing? If it isn't possible, how is a switch-case statement useful?

This is the code I'm using to test this

```
drop = random.randint(1,3)
inventory = []
def randomDrop(i):
    switcher ={
        1:
            "you got x"
            inventory.append(x)   #syntax error on this line         
        2: 
            "you got y",
            inventory.append(y)

        3: 
            "you got z",
            inventory.append(z)

    }
    return switcher.get(i,"you got nothing")
randomDrop(drop)
```

Comment: python doesn't support `switch`. you are using that is a dictionary and it is a data structure to hold data or references. use `if-else` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python doesn't support support switch case. The thing which you are using is dictionary. It is a key,value data structure.
Syntax of dict: {key1:value1, key2:value2}
but in place of value you are using multiple statement that's why the syntax error.

```
drop = random.randint(1,3)
inventory = []
def randomDrop(i):
    switcher ={
        1:
            "you got x"
            inventory.append(x)   #multiple statement instead of value or reference        
        2: 
            "you got y",
            inventory.append(y)   #multiple statement instead of value or reference        

        3: 
            "you got z",
            inventory.append(z)   #multiple statement instead of value or reference        

    }
    return switcher.get(i,"you got nothing")
randomDrop(drop)
```

Use `if-else` instead.

```
inventory = []
def randomDrop(i):
    if i == 1:
        inventory.append(x)
        return 'you got x'
    elif i == 2:
        inventory.append(y)
        return 'you got y'
    elif i == 3:
        inventory.append(z)
        return 'you got z'
    else:
        return 'you got nothing'

drop = random.randint(1,3)
randomDrop(drop)
```

See:
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do this. Let me know if it helps.

```
inventory = []
def randomDrop(i):
    if i == 1:
        inventory.append(x)
        print('you got x')
    elif i == 2:
        inventory.append(y)
        print('you got y')
    elif i == 3:
        inventory.append(z)
        print('you got z')
    else:
        print('you got nothing')

drop = random.randint(1,3)
randomDrop(drop)
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to do, just with a switch-statement. I wasn't aware that Python did not support them.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support switch case. You will have to use if-elif-else insetad of switch case.

Answer (score 0):

For a much more palatable and maintainable structure, you can use a helper function for the switch:

```
def switch(v): yield lambda *c: v in c
```

This will let you write the code in a C-like style:

```
for case in switch(i): 
    if case(1):
        inventory.append(x)         
        return "you got x"
    if case(2): 
        inventory.append(y)
        return "you got y"
    if case(3):             
        inventory.append(z)   
        return "you got z"
else:
    return "you got nothing"
```